# Check an attribute exists or not inside an object in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I like to fetch records which has null value of an attribute, the problem is this attribute exists inside another attribute am trying to do it via aws console i tried with contains and not contains didn't work, am attaching my structure here

```
{
  "pname": {
    "S": "Code"
  },
  "productInfo": {
    "M": {
      "maker": {
        "S": "Dummy"
      },
      "survey": {
        "M": {
          "water_products_you_own": {
            "L": [
              {
                "S": "Refrigerator Filter"
              }
            ]
          },
          "water_softener_brand": {
            "S": "Pentair"
          },
          "water_softener_type": {
            "S": "Cabinet"
          }
        }
      },
      "visible": {
        "BOOL": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am trying to find the records which **water_products_you_own** has null/empty value. please note i need to run this via AWS console. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`size`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions) which is not available on the web console.

Using the CLI:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name x \
--filter-expression 'size(prouctInfo.survey.water_products_you_own) > 0'
```

You'll probably have to add expression-attribute-names but it was too much for me to do from my phone.